# Why should I use the array memory location when assigning value?

Tags: c

I wonder why I should do this:

```
int myArray[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &myArray[i]);
}
```

Instead of this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please write why you down-vote! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) needs to know where in memory it should write the input it reads. To get a memory location a pointer needs to be used, and `myArray[i]` is not a pointer, it's a value.

To get a pointer, the ampersand (also known as the *address-of* operator) can be used. You could also rely on the fact that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, and use *pointer arithmetic* by just using `myArray` and adding an offset to the entry in the array. This works because `myArray[i]` is equivalent to `*(myArray + i)`, and similarly `&myArray[i]` is equivalent to `&*(myArray + i)` (but since the address-of operator `&` and the dereference operator `*` negates each other, it's the same as `(myArray + i)`, which is the same as `myArray + i`).

---

As for other types of variables, if the variable already is a pointer then you don't have to use the address-of operator (because if you did you would get a pointer *to the pointer*), for example when reading a string you only need to pass the actual variable. For non-pointer variables, you need to use the address-of operator.

Comment: Then do I have to do the same thing with a normal int variable?

Answer (score 4):

Because the `[]` is the array subscript operator, and the type of `myArray[i]` is `int` not `int *` which is what `scanf` is expecting when you use the `"%d"` specifier, you can do it with pointer arithmetic

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", myArray + i);
}
```

since `myArray` will behave as a pointer, when treated this way. But `myArray[i]` is in `int` so you need to pass the address of that `int`.